# Static sized outer elements, especially with .animate() to the right and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a work around for this problem, but I've been noticing some peculiar behavior while goofing around with html/javascript (jquery).

I've noticed that moving elements to the right and down beyond the borders of a containing element will resize the containing element.  As an example the reader is directed to http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ . Try dragging the box to the right or below the containing box.  This behavior is maddening.

How might you disable this annoying property?  Most of my elements are position: relative because placing them in the order they are written is not very useful at all.  This is just something I've noticed and would like some reasoning.

Comment: can you show us how resizing happens?

Comment: In the example provided, notice the scroll bars?

Comment: Also, $('#area').one('click',  
   function() {
    $(this).animate( 
     {
      opacity: 50,
      left: '+=500',
      top: '-=100',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(110, 138, 195)'
     }
    );
    
   }/*,

Comment: This guy will also introduce some scroll bars, leading me to believe the outer element is growing in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `containment`:

> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region. Possible string values: 'parent', 'document', 'window', [x1, y1, x2, y2].

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized after I asked this question there was likely an easy solution.  I could probably wrap the element in a div too, and then keep the outer div motionless.  Thanks again.  Or maybe disable horizontal scrolling.